# Oracle SQL Query to order by column value in different table

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I'm rather new to sql and am struggling with a statement. For simplicity, let's say I have two tables -
Table - JourneyOrder, and Table - ItemsToBuy.

JourneyOrder has list of cities, index of a particular city in a journey and who is taking the journey.
So:

```
City   Index Name
London 1     John
Sydney 2     John
Paris  3     John
Berlin 1     Jack
Paris  2     Jack
```

The other table has a list of items to buy, containing location (as in City), who needs to buy an item, and different characteristics of an item.

```
Item   Location   Weight   Price   Responsible
Pencil London     1        2       John
Glue   London     2        5       John
Car    Paris      1000     12000   John
Wallet Paris      3        20      Jack
```

I want to select all items a particular person needs to buy and order them by location. So if John's first route is London, I want items you can buy in London displayed first.

At the moment, I can use the following:

```
SELECT itb.item, itb.location, itb.price
FROM ItemsToBuy itb,
WHERE itb.responsible = 'John'
ORDER BY CASE
WHEN itb.location = 'London' THEN '1' 
WHEN itb.location = 'Sydney' THEN '2' 
WHEN itb.location = 'Paris'  THEN '3'
```

Now this is obviously terrible, as I need to 'hardcode' the order by part according to the journey each responsible is taking, how can I make it so it matches location of items table to city from journey table and uses the index from the journey table when these match.

Comment: You say Oracle but tag MySQL... Which one are you actually using?

Comment: What kind of order alphabetical or based on any field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want a `join`:

```
SELECT itb.item, itb.location, itb.price
FROM ItemsToBuy itb JOIN
     JourneyOrder jo
     ON itb.name = jo.name AND itb.location = jo.city
WHERE itb.responsible = 'John'
ORDER BY jo.index;
```